# Player gets stuck in certain directions

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-online

So the main part of my problem is that in GTA Online my player will get stuck going in a certain direction while running, walking, or driving and nothing I press will fix it. I can't change the direction they are moving or fix them if they're going around in circles. It lasts for a while as well.

Also, if I'm aiming and start moving, the character will continue moving in that direction and I can't take off my aim, fire the weapon, or change my direction. If I try to fire the game makes a loud "booping" (too deep to be a beep) sound.

It makes it very hard to do some processes as it happens fairly occasionally and I have no way whatsoever to stop it and none of the buttons work while it's happening. I have a gig of extra memory in the graphics control and have smooth fps. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Did you check your controls in game and see if you rebinded them? To double check, just set them to default. Is it a keyboard problem? Do you need to fix the keys? Did you enable Sticky Keys (happens alot with Minecraft players, highly recommend you disable it)? Can you use a Xbox 360 gamepad to PC? I hope some of these can help you sort out your question.

Comment: All of the controls are default and my keyboard works fine with any other game. I have both the sticky keys and filter keys shortcuts disabled as well. Unfortunately, I do not own an Xbox or PS gamepad either. I haven't seen anyone else reporting this problem though, which is strange considering it's just within that game.

Answer (score 1):

So I have sorted out the problem. It appears that if you use the Razer Cortez application to launch/boost your game then it will cause the problems. After I tried not using it all of the issues disappeared. So, if anyone else if having the problem and uses that application try running the game without it.